# Difference between FCELL, DCELL and CELL in GRASS GIS?

Tags: grass-gis

Can anyone clarify for me please the options in the "precision" parameter when calculating slope, aspect and curvature in GRASS GIS. What is the difference between FCELL, DCELL and CELL?

Answer (score 5):

You find an explanation of FCELL, DCELL and CELL in the introduction to 2D raster maps: http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/rasterintro.html

Data type `CELL` represents integer data values, `FCELL` single-points floating values and `DCELL` double-precision floating point values.

Answer (score 2):

From [GRASS Raster Library, GRASS GIS 7 Programmer's Manual](http://grass.osgeo.org/programming7/rasterlib.html):

> Raster map data can be of type CELL, FCELL or DCELL, they are defined
>   in "gis.h". CELL is a 32-bit signed integer, FCELL is an IEEE
>   single-precision floating-point, and DCELL is an IEEE double-precision
>   floating-point. 3D rasters (grid3d) is treated as DCELL (see related
>   library).